# Switching between two DC power sources with opposite currents

Tags: power-supply, dc

I'm running a 24 V DC motor, it allows for a change in direction of current to change the turning direction of the motor.

I have two exactly the same DC power supplies, with forward and reverse toggles (forward and reverse current).

What I am trying to do is to use each controller (one controller set to forward, the other to reverse) one at a time in order to switch the direction of the motor when a timer turns on each power supply, one at a time.

Unfortunately I keep blowing a 6 A fuse.

Power controller info:
Power: 100 W
Input voltage: 110 V
Output voltage: 24 V
Input current: 0.72 A
Output current: 6.6 A

Comment: Draw a schematic of your setup.

Comment: Without a diagram it is difficult to say what is happening, but if I had to guess, I would say that the motor is still spinning and it acts like a generator. When you apply the reverse voltage you then get a large surge of current as the power supply tries to slow down the motor and reverse it's direction or rotation. This will exceeded the steady state running current and blow the fuse. It's rather like connecting 2 batteries + to -, - to +. A very large current will flow until the weaker is exhausted

Comment: If your application can tolerate a short "dead" period when the motor is not powered, it might be an idea to allow it to stop before applying the reverse power.

Answer (score 1):

A single 24 V DC power supply and a DPDT relay should do.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

Comment: This is exaclty the direction and insight i needed. I believe i have found a 24v timer (https://a.co/d/1Qmb2v5) and a DPDT Relay i can use for my application (https://a.co/d/5nkQDwP) . Im just a little confused as to the pins. If i understand correctly, the 24v power supply will connect in parallel pins 1 and 8 on the relay and the input of the timer. After that i get a little foggy. The motor should be hooked to which pins? And what about the output of the timer?

Comment: Good! DPDT relay terminals 1 & 8 are for the coil and 2 to 7 are for the contacts. Timer terminals 1 & 2 are for the 24 V DC supply and 4 & 5 are for the output. The timer output is in series with the DPDT relay coil. A flyback diode is to be connected across the relay coil. The schematic has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer with more assurance will come with a diagram/schematic you should attach in a question. As you said:

> What I am trying to do is to use each controller (one controller set to forward, the other to reverse) **one at a time**.
> In order to switch the direction of the motor **when a timer turns on each power supply**, one at a time.

In this case, I may “guess” that:

- You are controlling two power supplies turning On-Off by a timer circuit, one timer per power supply, which most probably is connected to switch the Input: 110VAC.
- The Output of each power supply (PS) is connected using a switch, probably a DPDT switch, sometimes called “HH-switch”. That switch would reverse the polarity of the power applied to the DC motor, as illustrated [here](https://www.rollertrol.com/DC-motor-reverse-switch-diagram).
- For a 24V x 6A output, with 110VAC x 0.72A, it must be a switched mode (SMPS).
- I assume one SMPS is connected direct and the second one is connected reversed, to the same motor.

The above configuration seems to be the problem, as when any of the SMPS is switched on, it powers the motor, but also powers the other SMPS in reverse polarity, passing current through the “other” rectifier. It is a short-circuit and as it has a fuse to blow you are lucky that both SMPS are of the same capacity as likely just the fuse is blown.

See the following collage, adapted from [Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter), where the positive (red) and negative (blue) of the Left-SMPS are connected reversed to the right-SMPS, with a free-current path as a short-circuit.

[image]

**What you need**:
It is a **DPDT relay** (driven by your timer) and just **one SMPS**, as [shown here](https://www.electroschematics.com/dpdt-switch-relay/) [and here](https://320volt.com/en/spdt-relay-and-dpdt-relay/).
In case you need four states as Clockwise (On-Off) and Anti-clockwise (On-Off), you could still combine the use of those two timers: one for the direction relay, another for the motor On-Off.